# Making span elements have fixed width after trasitional animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very typical situation on which I have been pondering over a week now.
I have a table and each td has got a span element inside as shown in below HTML.On click of a button span elements move around and rearrange themselves.I chose putting span inside td because its much easier to work with spans for producing animation instead of moving tds around.

Everything is working except I want to have hovering effect on these spans, which I haven't been able to achieve.I have tried all css solutions stackoverflow or google has to offer, but none seems to work.

Initially all span elements are centered in tds but after animated movement dont stay centered.

Any help in css or html or jquery way is appreciated!!1

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><span id = "14">45</span></td>
    <td><span id = "15">1</span></td>
    <td><span id = "16">16</span></td>
    <td><span id = "17">10</span></td>
    <td><span id = "18">8</span></td>
    <td><span id = "19">19</span></td>
    <td><span id = "20">25</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><span id = "21">45</span></td>
    <td><span id = "22">9</span></td>
    <td><span id = "23">3</span></td>
    <td><span id = "24">23</span></td>
    <td><span id = "25">30</span></td>
    <td><span id = "26">5</span></td>
    <td><span id = "27">7</span></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    color: #3a3b36;
    font-size: 15px;
    /*display: inline;
      width: 82px;
      height: inherit;
      line-height: 100%;*/
}

td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript (trasitional animation):

```
for(i = 0; i < pos.length; i++){                  
     $('#' + i).css({
         position: 'absolute',
         top: pos[i].top,
         left: pos[i].left,   
     });              
 } //for loop ends
```

Answer (score 1):

About your issue having an hovering effect on your span, if you need simple effect you can use a css property :hover.
The code below will show the hovered span in red

```
td span:hover {
  background-color:red;
}
```

if you want to smooth your hover effect use the transition property.

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s;
}
td:hover {
  background-color:red;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

BTW, you can manage it with jquery :

```
$( "span" ).hover(
  function() {
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
},function() {
  $(this ).css("background-color","white");
}
);
```

The first function it's the mouseover handler and the second it's the mouse leave handler.

About your other issue, i need more to understand your goal, what is your onClick event ?